# Include file name and path after reading multiple files and writing to one 'big' file

Tags: unix

How do I include the file name and path after I merge many files into one 'big' file?

For example, I have files `TestMessage1.txt to TestMessage5.txt` in a directory `/temp/Errors/`. These files have the content of `Hello, this is test message 1 to Hello, this is test message 5` in them.

Merging TestMessage1.txt to TestMessage5.txt is pretty straight forward using the `cat * > outputfile.txt`

In the output file I get:

```
Hello, this is test message 1
Hello, this is test message 2
Hello, this is test message 3
Hello, this is test message 4
Hello, this is test message 5
```

How do I get my output file to look like:

```
/temp/Errors/TestMessage1 : Hello, this is test message 1
/temp/Errors/TestMessage2 : Hello, this is test message 2
/temp/Errors/TestMessage3 : Hello, this is test message 3
/temp/Errors/TestMessage4 : Hello, this is test message 4
/temp/Errors/TestMessage5 : Hello, this is test message 5
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Use `grep`:

```
grep "" * > outputfile.txt
```

If you want the full path of the files, use:

```
grep "" /temp/Errors/* > outputfile.txt
```

If you want `,` instead of `:`, pipe to `sed`:

```
grep "" /temp/Errors/* | sed 's/:/,/'> outputfile.txt
```

Comment: This grep command will match everything in the file and will print it out along with the file name. Try it.

Comment: I've noticed that a `:` is used to separate the file name from the files content is it possible to use `,` instead. This `grep` command  does not give me the path of the file

Comment: if you want more flexibility with the output, you might want to take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

That can be done with a (bash) script:

```
for i in * ; do
    while read line ; do
        full=$PWD/$i
        echo "$full , $line"
    done < $i
done
```

Advantage of this solution is it is more flexible than grep.

(***edited*** for multiple lines, comma instead of semicolon and full path)

Comment: This will only output the filename next to the first line in the file, not for all lines.

Comment: That's not specified in the question :)